# How to Replace txt processing with gif file in a script?

Tags: javascript, php

I made some experiment on my website webbatlas(dot)com but i can't change the txt-processing word with gif file. Please help or any idea on how to solve this?

basically i want some kind of loading gif file instead of txt...

here is the code where i have a problem:

```
download.textContent = (status==1&&data[1]==0)?"Processing...":data[1]
upload.textContent = (status==3&&data[2]==0)?"Processing...":data[2]
```

**And this is the whole script:**

```
    var worker = null
    function startTest() {
        document.getElementById('st-start').hidden = true
        document.getElementById('st-stop').hidden = false
        worker = new Worker('speedtest_worker.min.js')
        var interval = setInterval(function () { worker.postMessage('status') }, 100)
        worker.onmessage = function () {
            var download = document.getElementById
            var upload = document.getElementById
            var ping = document.getElementById
            var jitter = document.getElementById
            var ip = document.getElementById

            var data = event.data.split(';')
            var status = Number(data[0])
            if (status >= 4) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                document.getElementById('st-start').hidden = false
                document.getElementById('st-stop').hidden = true
                w = null
            }
            if (status === 5) {
                // speedtest cancelled, clear output data
                data = []
            }
            download.textContent = (status==1&&data[1]==0)?"Processing...":data[1]
            upload.textContent = (status==3&&data[2]==0)?"Processing...":data[2]
            ping.textContent = data[3]
            ip.textContent = data[4]
            jitter.textContent = data[5]
        }
        var ip_checkbox = document.getElementById("st-ip-checkbox")
        var dl_checkbox = document.getElementById("st-download-checkbox")
        var ul_checkbox = document.getElementById("st-upload-checkbox")
        var ping_checkbox = document.getElementById("st-ping-checkbox")

        var test_order=(ip_checkbox.checked?"I":"")+(dl_checkbox.checked?"D":"")+(ul_checkbox.checked?"U":"")+(ping_checkbox.checked?"P":"")

        worker.postMessage('start {"test_order":"'+test_order+'" }')

    }
    function stopTest() {
        if (worker) worker.postMessage('abort')
    }
```

Comment: Im a newbie/student... so please some enlighten answer..if you don't mind guys...thanks

Comment: set the background-image CSS property of the `download` to the GIF. You can google the JS syntax for doing this quite easily.

Comment: @ADyson - hi..please provide sample? thanks

Comment: I'll repeat: "You can google the JS syntax for doing this quite easily." No need for ppl here to re-invent the wheel. If you try and something based on your findings and then get stuck for some reason, please post your code here and explain any errors, and we can try to fix it. This isn't a free research service. This is a very simple job you can find dozens of examples already online

Comment: #st-download {
    background-image: url(images/loading.gif);
} - I did try to used this but still txt is showing

Comment: <span id="st-download"></span> i want to show here instead of "processing..." i wanted to load "loading.gif" ... so i what i do is #id and made a background image but nothing show...

Comment: `url('images/loading.gif')` - the filename needs quotes round it. Try to check more carefully the examples you are seeing. Do it like that and see if it works.

Comment: i did made a quote...and the background show but i wanted it to show before the actual counting...- actual event

Comment: Please check webbatlas.com :)

Comment: Ok so like I said right back in my first comment, replace `download.textContent = (status==1&&data[1]==0)?"Processing...":data[1]` with something which sets the background-image property of the `download` element. Again you can very easily google how to use JavaScript to set a CSS property on an element, instead of hard-coding it into your CSS file. You didn't think of searching for that already? In the question you already know it's that line which has to change, so I assumed you would know to search for JavaScript examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix:

`img class="hidden" src="images/loading.gif" id="loadDl"`

if(status==1){
if(data[1]==0) document.getElementById("loadDl").className=""; else download.textContent=data[1];
}